# R: How to set breaks of factorial x - axis in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, data-visualization

How can I set the break of the x-axis and drop every second factor? And also how can I adjust hover of ggplotly from factor(Year) to Year?

```
data <- data.frame (Year  = c("2017","2017","2017","2016","2016","2016","2015","2015","2015","2018" ,"2018" ,"2018"),
                  condition = c("normal","stress","Nitrogen" ,"normal","stress", "Nitrogen","normal","stress","Nitrogen","normal","stress","Nitrogen"),
                  value = c(22.221268,  1.598309 ,20.560815 ,17.337966,20.440174 , 9.074674, 11.739466,  1.905651, 32.270223, 14.271606 ,12.375446, 17.470793))


library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>%
  mutate(value = value / sum(value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=factor(Year))) + 
  geom_col(position="fill", width = 1, color = "white") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(value, accuracy = 0.1)), 
            position = position_fill(vjust = 0.50),
            color = "white") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How to show every other value on a discrete axis is a [duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52920047/903061). Using my answer from there, we can define the `every_nth` function. As for the `factor(Year)` tooltip label, the easiest way to avoid that is to convert the column to `factor` **before** plotting, so the aesthetic mapping is simply `x = Year`.

```
every_nth = function(n) {
  return(function(x) {x[c(TRUE, rep(FALSE, n - 1))]})
}

data %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>%
  mutate(
    value = value / sum(value),
    Year = factor(Year)  ## put this in mutate() before plotting
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill = condition, y = value, x = Year)) + 
  geom_col(position = "fill", width = 1, color = "white") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(value, accuracy = 0.1)), 
            position = position_fill(vjust = 0.50),
            color = "white") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = every_nth(2)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") -> p
  ggplotly(p)
```

[image]